# can anyone explain me the maths of this code?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded

Consider

`x_min` as -12.5,
`x_max` as 12.5,
`bits` as 8,
`x` is any value between -12.5 to +12.5 ,

Can someone explain me the math's of this snippet??

```
int float_to_uint(float x, float x_min, float x_max, unsigned int bits) 
{ 
  float span = x_max - x_min; 

  return (int) ((x- x_min)*((float)((1<<bits)/span)));
}
```

Comment: It maps the `float x` to an 8bit value. `-12.5` till `-12.4023..` will be 0, the next `25/256` part will be `1`, ...

Comment: `1<<bits` creates a bit mask such as 0x100 (bits==8), or if you will the decimal value 256. `1<<n` is also similar to 2^n. And finally `1<<n` is always a bug, particularly on a crappy 8 bit MCU where `1<<15` leads to value bits getting shifted into the sign bit = undefined behavior. It should be `1u << n`.

Comment: Also, using floating point arithmetic like this on an Arduino is very poor design, since it's an incredibly slow, obsolete 8-bitter and does not come with a FPU. It will slaughter everything that is called performance and memory use.

Answer (score 3):

If we ignore rounding, types and other little details, you could rearrange the separate parts a bit:

`(x-x_min) / (x_max-x_min)  * (1<<bits)`

This is basically scaling `x` to values of `0..2^bits` (=256) depending on where `x` is within `x_min`..`x_max`.

```
  x   |  result
------+----------
-12.5 |   0
 ...  |  
  0   | 128
 ...  |  
 12.5 | 256
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the function is to map values in the range `x_min` to `x_max` to values `0` to `2^bits`.

```
(int) ((x- x_min) / span * (1<<bits));
```

But there is some trickery being used here to help the optimizer. The last two values are re-aranged and computed first.  Mathematically it's the same but with floats it will round differently. A difference so minor there is actually a compiler flag allowing the compiler to ignore it (fast-math).

```
(int) ((x- x_min)    *    ((1<<bits) / span));
```

The cast to `float` is pointless as arithmetic promotion already turns `1<<bits` into a float and `float / float` remains `float`.

Now you might ask: What is the point of this transformation? The result is the (about) the same.

Here is my thought on that: In the source the `bits`, `x_min` and `x_max` will be literals or constants. So `span` is known at compile time too. The transformation allows the compiler to inline that function and compute `(1<<bits) / span)` at compile time. That leaves only one `float` subtraction and multiplication at runtime. It will therefore generate code that runs noticeable faster on something like an Arduino that has no FPU.

Comment: All the values are function parameters. Are you sure the compiler will be able to do much optimization there?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes. When the function is inlined the arguments turn into literals or constants so that is easy to optimize. But even without inlining modern optimizers will see a function being called with literals or constants and generate a partially evaluated version of the function. You end up with something like `int float_to_uint__OPT1(float x) { ... }` with all the literals and constants inserted. Obviously for this the function must be in the headers or same translation unit as the call. Or the code has to be compiled with whole program optimization (e.g. -fLTO).